# Add a Visualforce Page to the Page Layout Header

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

Is it possible to tag a Visualforce page in such a way that I could have it appear much like the standard functionality for related lists? I have a Visualforce page that "mimics" a related list, and I would like to be able to mimic the top header stuff as well.

This is the standard header I want to append with my Visualforce page quasi related list:

[image]

Comment: as far as I know there is no such  **VFtag**.

Comment: @sfdcweb Any idea how I could even replicate that header without making a completely custom Visualforce page of the whole record detail (which would be way out of scope anyways)?

Comment: You need to build custom VF page for this..

Comment: there is the `<apex:detail>` tag, but it's usually not flexible enough to be useful. Might be worth looking into though.

Comment: I've been wishing for this for ages... there's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrlGAAS) that directly corresponds to what you're trying to do, but thus far it only has two votes (including myself). Honestly, I'm really surprised they didn't consider this beforehand, since the usual purpose of an inline Visualforce page is to show... related data.

Comment: @sfdcfox It has my vote now. I was suprised as well that this is not already a feature. I have tons of related data shown on detail pages, and making a custom Visualforce page for each would be more tlc than I can provide for the dozens of standard and custom objects that need this.